# set .draggable revert by element id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Ok, I don't know if it is possible, but it looks like it should.

I have a bunch os math expressions (`3+2.2` `5.2+2.3` ...) and a bunch of answers both in draggable 'cards'. They are all draggable and have a column in which the student will drop the cards trying to match the expression and the answer.

So I need to validate if the answer is correct and disable both the draggables and droppable if so, and if not both cards have to change from revert false to true. The card that is currently being dropped works fine with `ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);` but even with the other card ID I can't change the revert value to true (`$(saveID).draggable('option', 'revert', false);`).

Each card and droppable slot have a data set to then and the cards data and id are saved in an array.

The droppables are set to accept any div from the expressions cards and the answers card respectively and there is a function in drop that validate then.

Is this enough to understand the problem? :x

Comment: This can be done via `drop`. Would need to see your code so far or an example to answer further. Also I know I answered a super similar question like a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that also performs the math to determine the answer. A smart test taker might view the source code to find out if there is an array of answers hidden in the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget questions">
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    1. Math
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <h5>Question</h5>
    <div class="card addend">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="card operator plus">
      +
    </div>
    <div class="card addend">
      2.2
    </div>
    <div class="card operator equal">
      =
    </div>
    <div class="card unanswered">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <h5>Answers</h5>
    <div class="card answer">
      4.5
    </div>
    <div class="card answer">
      3.2
    </div>
    <div class="card answer">
      5.2
    </div>
    <div class="card answer">
      5.5
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-header">
    2. Math
  </div>
  <div class="ui-widget-content">
    <h5>Question</h5>
    <div class="card addend">
      5.2
    </div>
    <div class="card operator plus">
      +
    </div>
    <div class="card addend">
      2.3
    </div>
    <div class="card operator equal">
      =
    </div>
    <div class="card unanswered">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <h5>Answers</h5>
    <div class="card answer">
      6.5
    </div>
    <div class="card answer">
      8.2
    </div>
    <div class="card answer">
      7.2
    </div>
    <div class="card answer">
      7.5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkAnswer(a1, a2, op, answer) {
  console.log(a1, op, a2, "=", answer);
  var sum;
  var ops = {
    "+": function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    },
    "-": function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    },
    "*": function(a, b) {
      return a * b;
    },
    "/": function(a, b) {
      return a / b;
    }
  }
  sum = ops[op](a1, a2);
  console.log(sum);
  return (sum == answer);
}

$(function() {
  $(".answer").draggable({
    revert: true,
    containment: "parent"
  });
  $(".unanswered").droppable({
    accept: ".answer",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var q = $(this).parent();
      var add1 = parseFloat(q.find(".addend").eq(0).html());
      var add2 = parseFloat(q.find(".addend").eq(1).html());
      var op1 = q.find(".operator").eq(0).html().trim();
      var ans = parseFloat(ui.draggable.html());
      var success = checkAnswer(add1, add2, op1, ans);
      if (success) {
        q.find(".unanswered").html(ans).toggleClass("unanswered answered");
        q.find(".answer").draggable("destroy").css({
          background: "#eee",
          color: "#ccc"
        });
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/prc8tzw5/

Revert is `true` here and you can see that in `drop`, if the answer is correct, it appends it to the card. It also disabled draggable on the answers so the user knows they have completed the question.